# Combining excel workbook sheet into one using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have roughly 30 excel workbooks I need to combine into one. Each workbook has a variable number of sheets but the sheet I need to combine from each workbook is called "Output" and the format of the columns in this sheet is consistent.

I need to import the Output sheet from the first file, then append the remaining files and ignore the header row.

I have tried to do this using glob/pandas to no avail.

Comment: show us the code you tried. pandas should be just fine using pd.concat()

Comment: Try this: `pd.concat(pd.read_excel(i, sheet_name='output') for i in os.listdir(".") if i.endswith('xlsx'))`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/). Here's a sketch of the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

compiled_wb = load_workbook(filename = 'yourfile1.xlsx')
compiled_ws = compiled['Output']

for i in range(1, 30):
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'yourfile{}.xlsx'.format(i))
    ws = wb['Output']
    compiled_ws.append(ws.rows()[1:]) # ignore row 0

compiled_wb.save('compiled.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 3):

Method shown by Clinton c. Brownley in [Foundations for Analytics with Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920038375.do):

execute in shell indicating the path to the folder with excel files ( make sure the argument defining all_workbooks is correct) and then followed by the excel output file as follows:

```
python script.py <the /path/ to/ excel folder/> < your/ final/output.xlsx>
```

script.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import glob
input_path = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]
all_workbooks = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_file, '*.xlsx'))
all_df = []
for workbook in all_workbooks:
    all_worksheets = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheetname='Output',    index_col=None)
    for worksheet, data in all_worksheets.items:
        all_df.append(data)
data_concatenated = pd.concat(all_df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file)
data_concatenated.to_excel(writer, sheetname='concatenated_Output',  index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Script errors: "all_worksheets.items()" instead of "all_worksheets.items" and axis=1 was needed for me on the pd.concat. "sheetname" must be "sheet_name" in the to_excel (at least recent version) and it should be "sheet_name" in the read_excel to avoid a warning.

Comment: This Works like a charm with the help of @OutfastSource solution and also installing the xlrd package but it just puts everything side by on axis = 1 and below each other on axis = 0.
I need it such that it copy pastes a worksheet then goes to the bottom-most  line and then copy pastes the same worksheet from the different workbook in that same folder. So how do i tweak this code for performing the desired Function ??

Answer (score 3):

This will probably get down-voted because this isn't a Python answer, but honestly, I wouldn't use Python for this kind of task.  I think you are far better off installing the AddIn below, and using that for the job.

[image]

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Click 'Merge all files from the folder in the Files location selection' and click 'Use a Worksheet name' = 'Output', and finally, I think you want 'First cell'.  Good luck!