# Error while appending many Excel files to one in Python

Tags: python, excel, automation

I am trying to append 10 Excel files to one in Python,

The code below was used and I am getting

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, 
you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Once I change sheet_name argument to None, the code run perfectly.
However, all the 10 excel files has three sheets and I only want specific sheet per excel file.
Is there a way to get it done?

your help is appreciated.

```
  import pandas as pd
    import glob
    path = r'Folder path'
    filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
    finalexcelsheet = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in filenames:
        df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name= 'Selected Sheet'), ignore_index=True,sort=False)
        finalexcelsheet=finalexcelsheet.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743741/combining-excel-workbook-sheet-into-one-using-python?rq=1

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I think you use `pd.concat` in wrong way - and maybe you don't even need it. `pd.concat` nead list with many `dataframes` to concatenate them - if you use `sheet_name=None` then `read_excel` may gives you list with `dataframes` (every sheet in separated `dataframe`) but if you use name then you have only one `dataframe` and it has nothing to `concatenate`. And if you have only one `dataframe` then you don't need `concatenate` or you should do `finalexcelsheet = pd.concat( [finalexcelsheet, pd.read_excel(...)], ...)`.

Comment: FIrst you could assing `read_excel()` to variable and check what you get when you use `sheet_name=None` and `sheet_name= 'Selected Sheet'`

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but problem is because you use `concat` in wrong way - or rather because you don't need `concat` in your situation.

---

`concat` needs list with `dataframes` like

```
concat( [df1, df2, ...], ...)
```

but `read_excel` gives different objects for different `sheet_name=...` and this makes problem.

`read_excel` for `sheet_name=None` returns list or dict with all sheets in separated `dataFrames`

```
[df_sheet_1, df_sheet_2, ...]
```

and then `concat` can join them to one `dataframe`

`read_excel` for `sheet_name=name` returns single `dataframe`

```
df_sheet
```

and then `concat` has nothing co join - and it gives error.
But it means you don't need `concat`.

You should directly assign `read_excel` to `df`

```
for file in filenames:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Selected Sheet')
    finalexcelsheet = finalexcelsheet.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```